# What is the longest professional chess game that ended in a checkmate?

Tags: checkmate, records, master-games, famous-games

Quite simply, what is the longest professional chess game that ended in a checkmate?

Comment: If you search for exactly that question, you get [the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_chess#Longest_game) as a first result.

Comment: @fuxia Are you sure? The games listed don't seem to have ended in checkmate.

Comment: @DM "The longest decisive tournament game" in the link.

Comment: @SmallChess Perhaps I'm missing something, but after White plays move 239 in that game, he hasn't yet checkmated Black.

Comment: If you really want to know, take all the games in the Mega Database (or the TWIC database). Sort them by all games ending in checkmate (I assume there's some way to do this). Then sort that subset by game duration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The game [Dann-Kovchan](https://www.chessbomb.com/arena/2017-dresden-open/07-Dann_Matthias-Kovchan_Alexander) ended with 217...Nc2#.

```
[Title "Matthias Dann-Alexander Kovchan, Dresden Open, Dredsen Germany, 4/8/17"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "433"]


1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 Ng4 7. Bg5 h6 8. Bh4 g5 9. Bg3 Bg7 10. Qd2 Nc6 11. Nb3 b5 12. h4 gxh4 13. Rxh4 Nge5 14. Nd5 Ng6 15. Rh1 Bxb2 16. Rd1 Bg7 17. c4 Rb8 18. c5 Nge5 19. Nf4 Bg4 20. Be2 Nc4 21. Qc1 Bxe2 22. Kxe2 Bb2 23. Qb1 Qc8 24. cxd6 exd6 25. Nh5 Rg8 26. Kf1 Rg6 27. Bxd6 Qg4 28. Bg3 Rd8 29. Rxd8+ Nxd8 30. Nf4 Rc6 31. Rh4 Ne3+ 32. Kg1 Qd1+ 33. Qxd1 Nxd1 34. Nd5 Nc3 35. Nd4 Rg6 36. Nf5 Nxa2 37. Nxh6 Nc3 38. Nf5 Ne2+ 39. Kf1 Nxg3+ 40. Nxg3 Kd7 41. Ne2 a5 42. Nec3 Rc6 43. Nxb5 Rc5 44. Na7 Bd4 45. Ke2 a4 46. Nb6+ Kc7 47. Nxa4 Ra5 48. Rh3 Bxa7 49. Nc3 Kd7 50. Rd3+ Ke8 51. Rd2 Nc6 52. g3 Rc5 53. Nd5 Rc4 54. Kf3 Kf8 55. Kf4 Kg7 56. Kf3 Nd4+ 57. Kg2 Ra4 58. e5 Ra5 59. Ne3 Rxe5 60. Ra2 Re7 61. Nd5 Rd7 62. Ne3 Ne6 63. Nf5+ Kf6 64. Nh4 Bc5 65. Nf3 Rb7 66. Nd2 Rb4 67. Rc2 Bb6 68. Ra2 Nc5 69. Ra3 Kg6 70. Rc3 f6 71. Ra3 Nd7 72. Rb3 Rd4 73. Nf3 Rd5 74. Rb2 Ba5 75. Re2 Nc5 76. Re7 Bd8 77. Nh4+ Kh6 78. Re8 Kg7 79. Re2 Nd3 80. Re6 Kf7 81. Ra6 Be7 82. Ra7 Ke6 83. Ra6+ Bd6 84. Rb6 Kd7 85. Rb7+ Bc7 86. Ra7 Nc5 87. Ra2 Bb6 88. Rb2 Ba5 89. Rb5 Bc3 90. Nf3 Kc6 91. Rb8 Ne6 92. Rc8+ Nc7 93. Rb8 Ra5 94. Ng1 Ra2 95. Nh3 Nd5 96. Re8 Be5 97. Kf3 Kd7 98. Rg8 Ne7 99. Rf8 Nf5 100. Rf7+ Ne7 101. Rf8 Ke6 102. Re8 Bc7 103. Rh8 Nc6 104. Re8+ Kf7 105. Re4 Bb6 106. Kg2 Ne5 107. Kf1 Nd3 108. Re2 Ra1+ 109. Kg2 Bc5 110. Kh2 Ne1 111. Ng1 Bb4 112. Rb2 Bc3 113. Re2 Ra5 114. Nh3 Rh5 115. Re3 Ba5 116. Ra3 Rb5 117. Ra2 f5 118. Re2 Kf6 119. Ra2 Bb6 120. Re2 Rb1 121. Ra2 Nd3 122. Kg2 Nc5 123. Nf4 Rd1 124. Rc2 Rd6 125. Rb2 Nd7 126. Ra2 Kf7 127. Rb2 Bc5 128. Rc2 Rd1 129. Re2 Bd6 130. Nh3 Nf6 131. Ra2 Ne4 132. Rb2 Ke6 133. Re2 Kd5 134. Ra2 Rb1 135. Ra5+ Nc5 136. Ra2 Rd1 137. Ng1 Ne4 138. Ne2 Ke6 139. Rc2 Ra1 140. Nd4+ Ke5 141. Ne2 Kf6 142. Ng1 Ra5 143. Nh3 Ke6 144. Ng1 Kd5 145. Nh3 Kd4 146. Rb2 Kd3 147. Rb3+ Kd4 148. Rb2 Ra7 149. Rb5 Bc5 150. Rb2 Kc3 151. Re2 Bd6 152. Re3+ Kd4 153. Ng1 Kd5 154. Re2 Ra3 155. Rb2 Bc5 156. Nh3 Kd4 157. Re2 Bd6 158. Ng1 Kc4 159. g4 Ra8 160. gxf5 Rg8+ 161. Kf1 Kd5 162. Nf3 Bc5 163. Nd2 Nd6 164. Nf3 Rg4 165. Re5+ Kc6 166. Ne1 Bd4 167. Ra5 Bb6 168. Re5 Bd4 169. Ra5 Nc4 170. Ra6+ Bb6 171. Nd3 Rg5 172. Ra4 Nd6 173. f6 Nf7 174. Re4 Bd8 175. Ke2 Kd5 176. Re8 Rf5 177. Re3 Rxf6 178. Rf3 Re6+ 179. Re3 Rh6 180. Nf4+ Kd6 181. Rh3 Rf6 182. Nd3 Bb6 183. Rh5 Nd8 184. Rb5 Kc6 185. Re5 Ne6 186. Nb4+ Kd6 187. Rd5+ Kc7 188. Nd3 Bxf2 189. Rh5 Bb6 190. Rh7+ Kd6 191. Rh5 Nd4+ 192. Kd2 Re6 193. Kc3 Nc6 194. Kd2 Ba5+ 195. Kd1 Re3 196. Nc1 Ne5 197. Rh2 Kd5 198. Re2 Rh3 199. Kc2 Nc4 200. Re7 Rc3+ 201. Kb1 Bb4 202. Re2 Rh3 203. Kc2 Rc3+ 204. Kb1 Bd6 205. Na2 Ra3 206. Nc1 Bf4 207. Na2 Rb3+ 208. Kc2 Rb2+ 209. Kd1 Ne3+ 210. Kc1 Rb3 211. Rd2+ Ke4 212. Rd8 Bg5 213. Rg8 Bf6 214. Ra8 Kd3 215. Ra4 Bb2+ 216. Kb1 Ba3+ 217. Ka1 Nc2# 0-1
```